# How to retrieve name of Javascript events attached to form in CRM 2016 server side

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm, dom-events, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to retrieve All the Javascript events/libraries attached to the form of particular entity from the server side.

I am able to retrieve the all the forms of that particular entity by using query expression

```
 QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("systemform");
            q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet() { AllColumns = true };
            q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("objecttypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, "account"));
            EntityCollection ec = serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(q);
```

I just need to know the Javascript library attached to OnLoad or OnSave Events in CRM form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying the formxml attribute on the form will give you what you are looking for. For e.g. to get all the attribute, event and function names on contact form:

```
var attributeEventsDetails =
                XDocument.Parse(xrmServiceContext.SystemFormSet.FirstOrDefault(form => form.Name == "contact").FormXml)
                    .Descendants("event")
                    .Select(descendants =>
                        new
                        {
                            AttributeName = descendants.Attribute("attribute"),
                            EventName = descendants.Attribute("name"),
                            FunctionName =
                                descendants.Descendants()
                                    .FirstOrDefault(childDesc => childDesc.Name == "Handler")
                                    .Attribute("functionName")
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI. systemform object doesn't contain entity forms. It contains dashboards - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334669.aspx

To get what you need you will have to get entity metadata that will contain forms. Description of a form is an Xml that contains what you need.

Comment: Thanks!

And what if I need that particular javascript code?

I need to show that code on some UI/ write on file.

Comment: Inside that Xml you will have a reference to JavaScript file used. So you can get that file using that reference.